# Insert JSON into variable in MongoDb php driver

Tags: php, mongodb, insert

i convert json file to array but it give me error in foreach invalid argument

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php'; 
$client = new MongoDB\Client;
$test = $client->test;
$createCollection = $test->restaurants;
$string = file_get_contents("D:\Database\primer-dataset.json");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);

foreach ($json_a as  $id => $item)
{
    $createCollection->insert( $item);


?>
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `$json_a`?

Comment: Yes it is empty i fix it now  thank you

Comment: @Pharaoh You should post that as an answer, as it seems to have solved safo's problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since it says `invalid argument`, `$string` is probably not valid JSON. Check the contents of `$string` and `$json_a` to see what exactly is happening.